# passing values in array in controller but only first array value is getting

Tags: arrays, ajax, laravel, foreach, controller

Here , i am passing array through AJAX and in controller i am writing a loop for get all values but only first array value is getting
**This is my response array code which is showing after dd($request->all())**
[image: dd response of array]

**This is my controller code getting only first array only**

```
  $formDataArray = $request->all();
        dd($formDataArray);
        foreach ($formDataArray as $formData) {
            $customInputName = $formData['customInputName'];
            $inputType = $formData['inputType'];
            $checkedValues = $formData['checkedValues'];

            dd($customInputName, $inputType, $checkedValues);

        }
```

i want all values as i want to insert each value in database.

whole function code

````
    // for remove duplicate form
    function removeLastElem() {
    document.getElementById('customField').lastChild.remove()
}
     // function for make copy of form
     function duplicateForm() {
            var elmnt = document.getElementById("addCustomField");
            var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
            document.getElementById("customField").appendChild(cln);
        }
         // for insert data into database
         function insertData(){
          $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
            }
            });
            var image = $('#image').prop('files')[0]; 
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('eventName', $('#eventName').val());
            formData.append('image', image);
            formData.append('price',$('#price').val());
            formData.append('location',$('#location').val());
            formData.append('desc',$('#desc').val());
            
            //custom fields
            const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form[name="addCustomField"]');
            const formDataArray = [];
        
            forms.forEach((form, index) => {
                const customInputName = form.querySelector('[name="customInputName[]"]').value;
                const inputType = form.querySelector('[name="inputType[]"]').value;
                const checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll('[name="validation[]"]:checked');
                const checkedValues = Array.from(checkboxes).map(checkbox => checkbox.value);
        
                formDataArray.push({
                    customInputName: customInputName,
                    inputType: inputType,
                    checkedValues: checkedValues
                });
            }); 
                $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: '{{ url('/inputForm') }}',
                        data: JSON.stringify(formDataArray),
                          formData,
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        processData: false, 
                        success: function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            var successDiv = document.getElementById('successMessage');
                            successDiv.innerHTML = response.message;
                            successDiv.classList.add('alert', 'alert-success');
                        } 
                    });
        }
    </script> ```
````

Comment: You know that dd() kills the process and therefor only will return once? because nothing is wrong with that data structure or how you get the values.

Comment: then how can i print all values? @mrhn

Comment: you could use dump() instead that does not stop. But instead tell us what you want to do with the data, seems like that part is left out and we are fairly vaguely describing what that should be done.

Comment: @mrhn i want to insert these all data into database ` foreach ($formDataArray as $item) {
            $customInputName = $item['customInputName'];
            $inputType = $item['inputType'];
            $checkedValues = $item['checkedValues'];

            // dd($customInputName);
            $customInput = new inputForm();
            $customInput->customInputName = $customInputName;
            $customInput->inputType = $inputType;
            $customInput->validation = $checkedValues;
            $customInput->eventid = '1';
            $customInput->save();
        }`

Comment: That should also work

Comment: but it is not working when i pass with others data like this ` data: JSON.stringify(formDataArray),
                          formData,`

Comment: i have added function can you check ? @mrhn

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    $formDataArray = $request->all();
   
    foreach ($formDataArray as $formData) {
        $customInputName = $formData['customInputName'];
        $inputType = $formData['inputType'];
        $checkedValues = $formData['checkedValues'];
        
        //get checked values from array like this  
        $checkedValue1  =  $checkedValues[0];
        $checkedValue2  =  $checkedValues[1];
        
        dd($customInputName, $inputType, $checkedValue1, $checkedValue2);

        
        if($customInputName, $inputType, $checkedValue1, $checkedValue2){
        //insert here
        }



    }
```

Comment: That all worked , data is inserting of this array now i am getting an issue in function which i added at upside

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, what issue are you facing in function? Is it in JavaScript?

Comment: check this post , i have elaborated everything https://stackoverflow.com/q/76875001/22000035